How to enable local DNS resolution on a small business LAN?
We have a small business LAN with one Router/Switch (a NetGear D6200). The devices on this LAN are:

2 Macs (1 connected via Ethedrnet, 1 wireless)
1 Synology NAS (via Ethernet)
1 Linux VM hosted on the NAS (via "virtual network card")

All devices can be pinged from each other via IP addresses in the network 192.168.0.0/24.
Also, the devices (the Macs, the NAS and the VM) have local DNS names:
ginger.local, dill.local, mint.local and basil.local.
However, ping cannot resolve thes ename. We get errors like

ping: cannot resolve basil.local: Unknown host (from the Mac to the VM)

or

ping: basil.local: Temporary failure in name resolution (from the NAS to the VM)

External DNS names are resolved on all machines. (E.g. on each machine I can do curl http://httpbin.org.), b\ut local DNS names obviously not.
From my understand the router/switch should resolve these names. If yes, how can I tell the router to do so?
Or do I need some other DNS resolution software (which I could e.g. run on the NAS)?

The .local namespace is usually reserved for multicast DNS (which Macs should support "out of the box", and Linux systems should support once you install the nss-mdns package).

@larsks Well, checking it in more detail, the macs understand the NAS name (but not the VM name), but the NAS understands no other names.

From my understand the router/switch should resolve these names the D6200 supports Dynamic DNS. It doesn't have the capability to host a DNS zone, although the Linux host could do that, and forward other queries to the current DNS, which is probably the ISP.

@GregAskew Thanks. I will read up on Dynamic DNS - do you think that could resolve the issue at hand?

No, but a simple DNS setup on either Linux or Windows should work fine.

nmbd and netbios mode for the MAC ?

As larsks notes in comments, the .local TLD is special. Current suggestion is to use lan or, better, mycompany.lan as the default DNS domain. On the D6200, there is no provision to set this in the DHCP server - the D6200 is very basic as to what information it provides in DHCP - so you must set the default domain in the DNS pages of the Macs and of the Linux virtual and the NAS. On the Synology, that's buried in the network settings - different Synology systems, and different vintages of their control software, have that in different places, so I can't help much there, or with the Linux virtual as you have provided no information about it. On the Mac machines, it's hiding in System Settings, Network, which NIC you're using, and look for the DNS Default Domain setting.

Thanks for chiming in! - So I have to do it on every machine on the network? I thought I can enter the DNS mappings in a central piece of DNS software (either on the router or maybe installed on the NAS).

The place you'd do that is on the DHCP server, which then would tell each machine what domain it was in. But your DHCP server is not capable of doing that. So yes, you'd do it once on each machine. In either case, the machine then tells the DNS server in the D6200 its name, and that's how it gets centralized.

Just to clarify, @tsc_chazz:  On each machine I have to list names and IP address of all other machines? Each machine already knows their own name.

No. Each machine needs to know only its own name, and its default domain; and all the default domains on each machine need to be the same.
